# Create Multiple Handler for webBrowser_.DocumentCompleted

Tags: c#, event-handling, webbrowser-control

This is my class:

```
class WebRequestWaiter
{
    private WebBrowser webBrowser_;
    private bool completed_ = false;
    private Guid uuid_ = Guid.NewGuid();

    public WebRequestWaiter(WebBrowser webBrowser)
    {
        webBrowser_ = webBrowser;
        webBrowser_.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) => _webBrowserDocumentCompleted(sender, e, uuid_));
    }

    private void _webBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e, Guid uuid)
    {
        if (uuid == uuid_)
        {
            completed_ = true;
            webBrowser_.DocumentCompleted -= (sender2, e2) => _webBrowserDocumentCompleted(sender, e, uuid);
        }
    }

    public void WaitForComplete()
    {
        while (!completed_)
            Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

In the main code:

```
private void button_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebRequestWaiter WRW = new WebRequestWaiter(webBrowser1);
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://example.com/search.php");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    webBrowser1.DocumentStream = receiveStream;
    WRW.WaitForComplete();
    //Code only continue when webBrowser1 Completed

    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("keyword").SetAttribute("value", textBox_Search.Text);
    foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
    {
        if (item.GetAttribute("value") == "Search Now")
        {
            WRW = new WebRequestWaiter(webBrowser1);
            item.InvokeMember("Click");
            break;
        }
    }
    
    WRW.WaitForComplete();
    //Code only continue when webBrowser1 Completed !BUT IT WON'T WAIT!
    //webBrowser1 contains the previous response

    foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("p")) 
    {
        if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "description")
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement item2 in item.GetElementsByTagName("u"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item2.InnerText); //this is debug
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to make the code run in 1 function and NOT like that:

```
private void button_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted1);
    DoSomethingThatChangeThePage();
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted2);
    DoSomethingThatChangeThePage();
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted2(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted3);
    DoSomethingThatChangeThePage();
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted3(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted4);
    DoSomethingThatChangeThePage();
}

//etc
```

I can do it like this but i'll lose in it when there will be more then 10, and i also can't make properly loops with this

(I did also used this in my first try but it did the same (just passed it when webBrowser1.Document still has the old(previous) information in it):
`while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();`)

Any solution to make work my class?

Comment: 1-hook all the button click events to the same function. 2-Store the button name that has been pressed into a variable. 3-on the DocumentCompleted handler do a `switch` to that variable and execute the correct code based on the last button pressed name.

Comment: Please don't ever call `ApplicationDoEvents()`. It's evil. It's only in the framework for backward compatibility for VB6. It'll end up causing insidious bugs that you'll never be able to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I did some debug and `_webBrowserDocumentCompleted` somewhy was called multiple time, before and after the document actually change.

This version works fine for me, if u call `WaitForComplete()` it only continue when document is changed:

```
class WebRequestWaiter
    {
        private WebBrowser webBrowser_;
        private bool completed_ = false;
        private Guid uuid_ = Guid.NewGuid();

        public WebRequestWaiter(WebBrowser webBrowser)
        {
            webBrowser_ = webBrowser;
            string hash_ = MD5Hash(webBrowser.DocumentText);
            webBrowser_.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) => _webBrowserDocumentCompleted(sender, e, uuid_, hash_));
        }

        private void _webBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e, Guid uuid, string hash)
        {
            if (uuid == uuid_ && hash != MD5Hash(webBrowser_.DocumentText) && !completed_)
            {
                completed_ = true;
                webBrowser_.DocumentCompleted -= (sender2, e2) => _webBrowserDocumentCompleted(sender, e, uuid, hash);
            }
        }

        public void WaitForComplete()
        {
            while (!completed_)
                Application.DoEvents();
        }

        private static string MD5Hash(string input)
        {
            StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] bytes = md5provider.ComputeHash(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(input));

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                hash.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));

            return hash.ToString();
        }
    }
```